# how to send published messages through interface in c# using callback

Tags: c#, interface, callback

suppose I have class 'A' that publishes messages using a web socket. My class 'B' which is interested in receiving these messages can only communicate with class 'A' through Interface 'I' which is their contract.
I know I should use callback, but how am I suppose to do it through interface 'I'?

Comment: Pass interface `I` as a parameter to your callback function?

Comment: could you explain it? which class should possess callback?

Comment: I don't know.  You haven't shown us any code.